# unwanted query string in RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using redirect statement like below to go to specific action with parameter

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(ActivityTypeController.Create), "ActivityType", new { selectedID = 34 });
```

and my action route configuration is

```
[Route("Create/{selectedID}")]
public IActionResult Create(int selectedID)
```

what I expected is

```
http://localhost:27945/ActivityType/Create/34
```

but it return

```
http://localhost:27945/ActivityType/Create?selectedID=34
```

I also use

```
RouteData.Values.Remove("selectedID")
```

but nothing changed!

I am using MVC6 with Asp.net 5 Template

**Updated:**

my redirected action is like below

```
[Route("Create/{selectedID}")]
    public IActionResult Create(int selectedID)
    {
        BL.BO.ActivityTypeBO bo = new BL.BO.ActivityTypeBO();
        ViewBag.Title = "title1";
        ViewBag.Description = "some desc";
        var data = bo.GetAll().Where(p => p.ParentID == null).OrderBy(p => p.Title);
        SelectList parents;
        parents = new SelectList(data, "ID", "Title", selectedID);
        ViewBag.Parents = parents;
        return View();
    }
```

and I use **RoutDate** just before redirect to action

```
RouteData.Values.Remove("selectedID");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ActivityTypeController.Create), "ActivityType", new { selectedID = 34 });
```

Comment: are you using RouteData.Values.Remove("id"); before RedirectToAction...Can show the syntax how you are using to remove selectedID.

Comment: And please show whats going on on your redirected action.

Comment: @stylishCoder updated my question for further information thanks for help!

Comment: @SeM updated my question for further information thanks for help!

Comment: Routes are matched in order from first registered to last registered, and the first match wins. Most likely you have another route registered (before the route in question) that matches the route values `controller="ActivityType", action="Create"` that does not contain a `selectedID` route key, which is why it is being appended to the query string. To fix this issue, you need to ensure your routes are registered in the right order (using `Order` property on the `Route` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

MVC will add the parameters like a query string.So, in cases like yours, you need to append it to the action param of RedirectToAction method.Below is the code

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(ActivityTypeController.Create) + "/34" , "ActivityType");
```

Comment: you sure about that, I think there should be a better way to solve this issue!

Comment: Yes. Sure on that. The routeValues parameter of RedirectToAction method will append the params to querystring.And there is not other paramter for that method which will render the way you require.

Comment: So, what's the best way to call action with parameter in MVC 6 ?

Comment: You have tried with mvc6 RedirectToAction method and it also works the same way as before versions. Then the answer provided will do the job